# Input arguments using getArgs returns nothing

Tags: haskell, io, arguments

I am trying to understand getArgs but I am getting a weird behavior that I am not understanding.  Here is my program:

```
getMyArgs :: IO [String]
getMyArgs =do
         x <- getArgs
         return x
```

I run this and get:

```
*Main> hello <- getMyArgs
*Main>
```

Why doesn't it return my argument passed?  I tried to put in a " show() " but that turns it into a String instead of a [String]

Comment: The code you have shown shouldn't ever terminate - it is an infinite loop.  How about you show your actual code and how you tried to run it.

Comment: This is my code

Comment: ahhh sorry about that. I see what you are saying

Comment: That makes much more sense. You've bound `hello` to the result of `getMyArgs` so now you just need to write `hello` or `print hello` in order to see its value.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: note that `getMyArgs` calls `getArgs`, not `getMyArgs`, so there is no recursion.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well now that its been edited that is the case, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getMyArgs :: IO [String]
getMyArgs =do
         x <- getArgs
         return x
```

The do notation desugars to:

```
getMyArgs :: IO [String]
getMyArgs =  getArgs >>= \x -> return x
```

Using the right identity we can rewrite this to:

```
getMyArgs :: IO [String]
getMyArgs =  getArgs
```

So you've just defined a new name for `getArgs`.  Now why does getArgs not show your program arguments? Well it appears you didn't provide any program arguments.  In the interpreter it can be tricky to provide arguments - one way is to `:set` them:

```
Prelude> :set args hello world
Prelude> import System.Environment
Prelude System.Environment> getArgs
["hello","world"]
```

EDIT: Oh you might be looking to print the value you bound.  Consider:

```
Prelude System.Environment> hello <- getArgs
Prelude System.Environment> print hello
["hello","world"]
```

Thanks to @4castle for this observation.

Comment: For some reason I thought "hello <- getMyArgs" was providing hello as the argument.

Comment: No, `hello` is a variable name that contains the arguments as a list of String values.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your Haskell program is compiled to an executable `foo`. When you call your program, you want to pass some runtime arguments to your program eg `foo param1 param2` . Depending on the values of *param1* and *param2* you will take different actions in your program.

Now with the *getArgs* function you get access to these parameters in your Haskell program.

In GHCi this argument passing can be simulated. Either with the `:set args paarm1 param2` command as shown in the answer of Thomas M. DuBuisson
or you call your main program in GHCI with `:main param1 param2` .

In both scenarios *getEnv* will return `IO ["param1", "param2"]`